# a href changes visibility of a button/div?

Tags: html, css

Very strange thing happening here in IE7, IE8: [index.php](http://www.donina.com/redmustard/graeme_clark/index.php) versus [index-2.php](http://www.donina.com/redmustard/graeme_clark/index-2.php)

As you can see on index.php, the button below "Registration details" is visible.  On index-2.php, the button is not. The only difference between these two pages is the `<a href>`.  On index.php the `<a href>` is to an existing page (but the incorrect page) our-partners.php.  On index-2.php, the `<a href>` is to the correct (and existing page) register-now.php.

Can anyone please explain why this is happening? I'm going crazy trying to understand!

Despite changing the html & css as suggested below, it's still not working correctly seemingly because of the `<a href>`!

MTIA!

Comment: Which browser are you testing in? It's there on both pages in Chrome 8.0.552.224

Comment: It also works correctly with FireFox 3.6.10.

Comment: IE7 and IE8, sorry - edited post too late for your comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I can see it on both pages (FF 3.5). However, I would advise against putting an `<a href>` around a `<div>` like that. It might be a better idea to just use `<a href="..." class="read-more">` and add `display: block;` to the style of your `read-more` class. This may or may not solve your original problem as well ;)

Comment: It is semantically *wrong* to have a div within an a. inline elements should not contain block level elements :) +1

Comment: What he said! Thanks, I forgot to include the "why" bit :)

Comment: thanks. i'll give this a go. my mind has turned to mud and i couldn't work out how to do it better!

Comment: Okay, this hasn't worked. I've changed the html & css as suggested. Still, it's not working in IE7 & IE8. Interestingly, the hover image swap on that link isn't working now in Chrome. Any other ideas? Please? 8-(

Comment: Are you sure? It seems to work ok in IE7 over here. A correction: I was using FF 3.5 earlier, not Chrome. I'll change it.

Comment: Well, I'm using IE Tester and index.php is using the incorrect url for the <a href>, and the button is visible.  index-2.php is using the correct url and the button is not visible. Testing both IE7 and IE8.

Comment: Also, the hover over the problem button isn't working. I could scream.

Comment: Ah wait, I think I'm looking at the wrong button. You're talking about the "register now" button, right? I believe its `:hover` css is off, it's saying `A.registerbutton:hover { BACKGROUND: url(images/b-register.png) no-repeat left top }` instead of moving the background position to show the grey version. Does this help?

Comment: Yes, the hover is now working, thanks so much. I've been staring at this site for 14 hours now and it's now like staring at a test pattern. Nothing makes sense! But still the problem of the urls persists. index.php and the register button linking to the incorrect page means that the register button is visible. index-2.php and the register button linking to the correct page means that the register button is not visible. IE7 and IE8 only.

Comment: The strange thing is, I can see the button fine on both pages in IE7. I know this is a terrible thing to say, but have you tried cleaning your cache? If that fails, maybe try swapping the urls in the files, if only to reassert that that can't possibly be the problem ;) Or, make a completely new index3.php file with the code of index.php and the correct url? I know none of this makes any real sense, but although as I said I can't reproduce the problem I really feel your pain.

Comment: Holy moly. Okay, I closed and then reopened IE Tester and cleared the cache. And that worked. I can go to bed now. Thank you so much Spiny Norman, I could kiss you for your help and sympathy !